# PS C:\Users\Moustapha\Desktop\projet_ionic>

Tags: ionic-framework

PS C:\Users\Moustapha\Desktop\projet_ionic> ionic generate page details
[ERROR] Sorry! ionic generate can only be run in an Ionic project directory.

```
    If this is a project you'd like to integrate with Ionic, create an ionic.config.json file.
```

PS C:\Users\Moustapha\Desktop\projet_ionic>

Comment: This isn't very clear. What have you tried so far? Have you `cd` in to the folder in your terminal?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.